# Geom aesthetic only for some level or category

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I am trying to control geom aesthetic for some category or level, example

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggrepel)
  library(treemapify)

    set.seed(123)
    Cases = round(rnorm(16, 500, 22))
    Country = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 16 )]
    df = data.frame(Cases,Country)

    df=rbind(df, data.frame(Country='Total', Cases = round(sum(df$Cases))))

   ggplot(df, aes(area =Cases , fill = Country, label = Cases)) +
        geom_treemap() +
        geom_treemap_text(fontface = "bold.italic", colour = "white", place = "centre", grow = T,  min.size = 1)
```

This produce this plot:

[image: plot1]

My goal is get a graph like that, where Total size is similar to others countries to make this example I delete Total row, only for the purpose to display the size of the differents numbers in each country.

```
    df=df[!grepl('Total',df$Country),]

    ggplot(df, aes(area =Cases , fill = Country, label = Cases)) +
        geom_treemap() +
        geom_treemap_text(fontface = "bold.italic", colour = "white", place = "centre", grow = T,  min.size = 1)
```

[image: plot2]

My goal is get the total size like the size of others Countries. To do this i tried to control grow = F with a filter, this is my example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(area =Cases , fill = Country, label = Cases)) +
geom_treemap() +
{if(df$Country=="Total") geom_treemap_text(fontface = "bold.italic", colour = "white", place = "centre", grow = F,  min.size = 1)} +
{if(df$Country!="Total") geom_treemap_text(fontface = "bold.italic", colour = "white", place = "centre", grow = T,  min.size = 1)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the size same you can give `area` a static value instead of using `cases`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(treemapify)


ggplot(df, aes(area = 10 , fill = Country, label = Cases)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(fontface = "bold.italic", colour = "white", 
                    place = "centre", grow = T,  min.size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if its possible only control size (area) for Total but not for others countries?

Comment: When you put `area = cases` the size varies based on number of cases. So Total has a very big size because `cases` is very big number for it as compared to other. If you want to handle it manually you could create a new column called `size` with `df$size <- df$cases` and then change the value of `Total` to whatever you want (eg `df$size[17] <- 1000`) and use `area = size` in `aes`.

Comment: Great! Thanks again